# How to clear Python variable that has the same name as a function and to make function work again

Tags: python

I have a script that runs for about an hour. I run it in the python shell, and then play around with the generated variables in the shell. The problem is, I accidentally created a variable that has the same name as a function:

```
calcError = calcError(someVars)
```

so when I try to call the function again,

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I know that normally I can clear variables by setting them to `None`. But that doesn't restore the function:

```
calcError = None
someOtherVar = calcError(someVars)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

How can I restore the function without having to run the script again?

Comment: You can't, because you replaced the name entirely. Re-create the function from the original source lines.

Comment: If the function is defined in a module, you could just re-bind the name with `from module import calcError`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok that worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the function in your interactive session, then you replaced the global name with another object and you cannot get the old object back. Re-run the `def calcError(...):` lines you executed in your shell earlier.

If the function is imported from a module, just re-import it again to rebind the global name:

```
from modulename import calcError
```

That's because the function object is still referenced in that module's namespace; importing merely creates another reference to the same object.